# NServicebus 4.2 logs warning about message not found in registry?

Tags: nservicebus

Hi we have recently upgraded to NSB 4.2 from 3.5.

After the upgrade NSB logs a warning

```
Message header 'SomeNamespace.ISomeEvent__impl, NServiceBus.Scheduling.Messages__impl, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' was mapped to type  'SomeNamespace.ISomeEvent__impl' but that type was not found in the message registry, please make sure the same message registration conventions are used in all endpoints, specially if you are using unobtrusive mode. MessageId: 37cbec38-7957-4b7a-b313-804f6ed3b6fd\37679827
```

If i debug i can see we have a entry in message registry for SomeNamespace.ISomeEvent
But the type it looks for is SomeNamespace.ISomeEvent__impl.

We have not changed our unobtrusive settings after the upgrade, so question is what has changed?

I can see the logging has changed in change set [5f1c72ba](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/commit/5f1c72baf71191dd3d6339dbd5a03ca4748d28d0), seems the file has been renamed or something so cant seem to see full history.

Have we always had the problem, but only recently logging behavior in NSB has changed?

Comment: are you self hosting or using the NSB host?

Comment: We are using the NSB host.

Comment: 4.3 had some fixes related to message inheritance. Can you retry using 4.3. If its still an issue, can you send us a repro?

Comment: I will try to use 4.3.

Comment: It was solved by using a later nsb version,  can't tell you which one, not at work atm.

Comment: Has this issue come back?  We're on NSeviceBus 5.2.9 and I'm currently stumped with the same message, "NServiceBus.Unicast.Messages.MessageMetadataRegistry Message header 'X' was mapped to type 'X' but that type was not found in the message registry, please make sure the same message registration conventions are used in all endpoints, specially if you are using unobtrusive mode."